# Single character makes iOS crash

Tags: ios, fonts, crash, character

Here's the situation, I'm using a custom font to render some special characters (icons) for an iOS app. I have used many of the characters in that font and everything is just fine **BUT** when I use one character (it doesn't matter where) the app crashes.

This problem **ONLY** occurs with that single character in that font, if I use any other character nothing bad occurs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific WHICH special character you are talking about & WHERE you are using it. Based on your given limited information, all I can think of is try using ASCII of that problematic character.

Comment: Hi Skypirate... the thing is that the character is within a font created with Fontello (custom designs)... I use some of these characters everywhere (UILabels, UIButtons, Storyboard etc) and everything works just fine except if I use one of those... I just wanted to know if this was a "common" issue or something